# Progressive migration with Encrypted Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, objective-c-blocks, core-data-migration, encrypted-core-data-sql

Source Reference:[Custom Core Data Migrations](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html)

I have been using a github module (Encrypted Core Data by Gavin Black) and it has come to my attention that automatic lightweight migration has the **limitation** where if:

> 1) If the device has a data model that is more than one version behind the most up-to-date model OR
>
> 2) No data model is created for the current version to the latest version

Automatic lightweight migration will not successfully migrate as expected. I ended up searching on Google and found the resource as pasted in the top confirming my suspicions.

A solution was proposed called the **progressive migration** and it worked successfully for a regular SQLite. However, when I tried to carry this implementation to ECD, I am running into problems. The exception is as follows:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ': An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled. Key path: migrationProgress Observed object: Change: { kind = 1; new = "0.02083333"; }

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: I can see that you're struggling, and found this for you: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2150667&seqNum=5. Does that help at all?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Hey everyone,

So I've made a separate project for anyone who is interested in trying to help figure this progressive migration issue out.

https://github.com/sdwornik/ECD-Migration

I've taken a whirl at it to the best of my abilities and have made some progress, but its still not working entirely. Please feel free to take a whirl at it too if you're interested in helping solve this problem.